# Pressure equalising in systems

Tags: thermodynamics

Why does the pressure in two interconnected systems, say two connected glass bulbs, always end up equalised even if the temperatures are maintained different in both of them?

Comment: If you have two connected chambers of gas at different initial pressures and temperatures they will eventually reach equilibrium, same temperature and pressure.

Comment: @Charlie The OP states that the temperatures are "maintained". I would interpret that to  mean each bulb is in thermal contact with a heat reservoir.

Comment: What do you mean by the temperatures being "maintained". I'm interpreting that to mean each bulb is immersed in a constant temperature thermal reservoir. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That's what I was getting at, how exactly you set that up depends on how you interpret the wording of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on the assumption that the temperatures of the bulbs are being "maintained" by external thermal reservoirs in contact with the bulbs and that the bulbs are made of thermally conductive material.

The initial pressure difference causes a flow of gas from the high pressure side to the low pressure side. Since there is no where for the gas to go except between the bulbs (since the bulbs are closed containers), eventually the flow will stop when the pressures will equalize.

Likewise the temperature difference between the bulbs will result in heat transfer from the bulb with the higher temperature gas to the bulb with the lower temperature gas. If the bulbs were thermally isolated from the surroundings, the temperatures would eventually equalize. However, since the temperatures in the bulbs are "maintained" by some external (to the bulbs) means, such as the bulbs being in contact with thermal heat reservoirs (i.e., constant temperature sources), the temperatures of the bulbs remain constant. In effect, heat is continually transferred between the reservoirs and the gas simply facilitates that transfer without changing temperature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it, there's nothing opposing the gas flow there. That helped, thanks a lot!